# JSON / JQUERY - ajax post, how to process XML data in success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Hi I am doing a ajax post via a JSP. I am posting JSON data in string format (parsed using parseJSON, then I use the JSON stringify to return to a string.

This post works fine. But what I am not sure how to do, is basiclally I sending this to a a client gateway, which translates this jsonString into XML to do some internal processing. This internal work will generate an XML response, that needs to be sent back to my JSP. I plan on receiving and this XML in the ajax post 'success' function facility.

So far I have been able to make this work with the success function "data" item being HTML. But I am not sure how this can be done when I want to XML. How do I do this? How do I receive XML, and how do you host/find/display the XML for it to be returned in the sucess 'data' function?

My other option, is that if it is not XML that I want to recieve, I could possibliy receive JSON data. How can I host/find/display JSON data for it to be returned in the sucess 'data' function?

This is my post code:

```
$.ajax({   
type:       "POST",   
url:        suppliedURL,   
data:       "jsonData=" + jsonString, // I have already done a json stringify on this.
success:    function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {   
                alert('Success : ' + data);   .. I want this to be XML
                alert('textStatus : ' + textStatus);   
                alert('jqXHR : ' + jqXHR);   
                var jsonJqXHR = JSON.stringify(jqXHR);  
                alert('jsonJqXHR : ' + jsonJqXHR);   
},   
error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){   
    alert('Error xhr : ' + xhr.status);   
    alert('Error thrown error: ' + thrownError);   
},  
//complete: alert('complete'),  
dataType:   "text" // xml, json, script, text, html                          
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `dataType` to `xml`; after that `data` in the `success` method will be an [XML document](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/default.asp).